# Print sliced vector results in "Sized is not satisfied"

Tags: rust

I am trying to slice a vector and print it simultaneously in Rust. This is my code:

```
fn main() {
    let a = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    println!("{:?}", a[1..2]);
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `[{integer}]: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:6:5
  |
6 |     println!("{:?}", a[1..3]);
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ trait `[{integer}]: std::marker::Sized` not satisfied
  |
  = note: `[{integer}]` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
  = note: required by `std::fmt::ArgumentV1::new`
  = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate
```

How do I print this sliced vector?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use a reference; it worked for me in Rust 1.13.

```
println!("{:?}", &a[1..3]);
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying to understand the difference between arrays, slices, vectors and box. Do you know any good tuts for it? I specifically want to understand how box works and what do they mean when they say that vectors are smart pointers.

Comment: it explains the difference between arrays, slices and vectors pretty good

Comment: I went through this but it does not explain clearly the difference between box, vectors and arrays.

Comment: Maybe this helps, it explains various wrapper types and also boxes [link](http://manishearth.github.io/blog/2015/05/27/wrapper-types-in-rust-choosing-your-guarantees/)

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful :)